# RTL lables in mapbox android

Tags: android, mapbox, right-to-left

I am using mapbox SDK in android project,  Arabic and Hebrew are both written from right-to-left (RTL) instead of the left-to-right (LTR). my problem is persian lables Are written from Left to right. like this :

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Jmr.png)

As you see in screenshot the titles or rendered wrong in Persian Language. for example I marked 3 labels:
بهارستان is wrongly rendered as ن ا ت س ر ا ه ب

بازار is wrongly rendered as ر ا ز ا ب

سنگلج is wrongly rendered as ج ل گ ن س

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? Capturing form [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/7774#issuecomment-273620456) that this should be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

my problem solved. i just update mapbox to latest version. thanks

compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.2.0-beta.3@aar')